# Cuantas veces aparece un numero dado en un intervalo del 1 al 100

Tags: javascript

Tengo un ejercicio bàsico que hacer, pero estoy atascado. El ejercicio me pide que cuente cantas veces aparece el numero 6 entre 1 y 100.

Yo tengo esto:

```
const MAX = 100;
const valor = 6;

var i;
var numero;
var q;
var c = 0;

for ( i = 1; i < MAX; i++) {
    numero = i;
    q = 0;

while (numero > 0) {
    if (numero % 10 == valor) {
    q = q +1;
}

numero = (numero / 10);

   
}
 
    if (q > 1) {
    c = c +1;
}

}

console.log ("Hi ha " + (c).toString() + " números entre l’1 i el 100 amb dos o més " + (valor).toString()) ;
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracais

Comment: A que te refieres?

Comment: El tema es que busco un 6 entre el numero 1 y el numero 100. Es decir. 6,16,26,36 etc.....

Comment: Ya... cambiá el signo `>` por un `>=` !!! No quiero seguir jugando a las adivinanzas

Comment: Ostia......ahora ya funciona!

Comment: Me cuenta que hay 11 seises pero no es verdad......que me falla mas en el codigo?

Comment: Depurar tu código, agregar `console.log()` para ir imprimiendo qué valores va tomando y ver que debería ser una división entera con `Math.floor(numero / 10)`

Comment: ostia......ahora si......ahora ya me devuele 19 numeros. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola joan , pero te deberia devolver 20 , no estas contemplando el 66

Answer (score 1):

```js
let find = 6
let contador = 0
for(let i =1; i <= 100; i++){
  if((i.toString()).search(find) != -1){ 
  contador++
  console.log(i)
  }
}
console.log("\nSale un total de: "+contador+" veces")
```

Answer (score 0):

joan para el caso no hace falta las matematicas si podes valorar el recorrido de los numeros como strings y con el metodo indexOf verificar la busqueda del numero , con las plantillas de cadena de texto `` te ahorras convertir el numero en un string para evaluarlo  y la segunda condicion contempla si el numero se repite doble

```js
    const max = 100
    const cualAparece = 6
    let contador = 0
    let aparece=0
    
    while(contador<=max){
        if(`${contador}`.indexOf(cualAparece)!= -1){
            aparece++
        }
        if(`${cualAparece}${cualAparece}`==contador){
            aparece++
        }
        contador++
    }
    
    console.log(aparece)
```